# How might the Qur'an allow for marriage with 9 or 18 women?

Tags: tafseer, sects, polygamy

In a conversation someone claimed that certain sects allow for a greater limit on polygamy such as 9 or 18 women based on their understanding of the Qur'an. Is this true? How do they argue their stance?

Comment: What sects? I haven't heard of these sects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stance is attributed to some of the Khawarij and some Shi'as although I think that it is not accepted by the vast majority of the latter. And it is certainly not accepted by the Ahl al-Sunnah. In short it is based on the possible interpretation of 4:3 as follows:

> انكحوا ما طاب لكم من النساء مثنى وثلاث ورباع
>
> marry the women you like, two **or** three **or** four
>
> marry the women you like, two **and** three **and** four
>
> marry the women you like: two, two **and** three, three **and** four, four
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:3](https://quran.com/4/3?translations=20)</sup>

The conjunction و can mean 'and' (addition) as in the following verse:

> فصيام ثلاثة أيام في الحج وسبعة إذا رجعتم تلك عشرة كاملة
>
> Fast of three days during Hajj and of seven when you have returned. Those are ten complete [days].
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:196](https://quran.com/2/196?translations=20)</sup>

Or it can be used as a synonym for 'or' as in the following verse:

> تقوموا لله مثنى وفرادى
>
> Stand for Allah in pairs <s>and</s> *or* individually
>
> <sup>— [Quran 34:46](https://quran.com/34/46?translations=20)</sup>

Hence a group interpreted 4:3 as 'marry two and three and four' which is 2+3+4 = 9

Others further argued that the use of the expression  مثنى وثلاث ورباع  indicates pairs, i.e. pairs of two, three and four. Hence they claimed that it means (2 x 2) + (2 x 3) + (2 x 4) = 4+6+8 = 18

Some even claimed that there is no limit.

Other than the verse, they relied upon the example of the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ - as he had nine wives at the time of death ([Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:3197), [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5067)). And we are told to follow his example.

The majority however do not accept these interpretations because:

- It is contrary to the interpretation of the verse from the Sunnah. It is recorded that before accepting Islam [Naufal bin Mu’awiya](https://sunnah.com/mishkat:3177) had five wives, [Ghailan bin Salamah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1953) had ten wives and [Harith ibn Qays](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2241) has eight wives. The Prophet ﷺ told each of them to keep any four wives and to divorce the rest. This proves that the limit is four.
- The Quran is eloquent. It is argued that if nine (تسع) or eighteen (ثمانية عشر) were meant then using the names of those numbers might have been more appropriate.
- It is opposed to consensus of the reputable scholars.
- None of the Sahaba or Tabieen are known to have married more than four women.
- In this issue the law for the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ is different from the law for the rest of the Ummah. The Prophet ﷺ is excluded from 4:3 as he was specifically permitted to marry as many women as he wished ([Quran 33:50-51](https://quran.com/33/50-51?translations=20)). And also because the limit in 4:3 is imposed to reduce the chance of injustice to the wives, whereas the Prophet ﷺ can not be unjust.

---

**Ref:**

> وقال بعض الخوارج: الآية تدل على جواز تسع: مثنى باثنين، وثلاث بثلاث، ورباع بأربع، ومجموع ذلك تسع، وبعض منهم تدل على ثمانية عشر: مثنى اثنين اثنين، وثلاث ثلاثة ثلاثة، ورباع أربعة أربعة، ومجموع ذلك ما ذكر، وهذا خرق للإجماع
>
> <sup>— [Mughni al-Muhtaaj](https://shamela.ws/book/11444/1959)</sup>

Also see  [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura4-aya3.html#qortobi),  [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura4-aya3.html#katheer), [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/baghawy/sura4-aya3.html#baghawy)